# HTML, JQuery seporation of loading divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I currently have a page that loads slow and would like to make the user experience more enjoyable.  I would like to load each div so when a div is read() fade in using jQuery.  Currently my code works but it loads everything at the same time and fades in.  I would like it to load in order of div placement.  Below is an example code of loading 2 divs with large tables in them.  I would like each table to show up as soon as it's ready.  The first one should be ready before the second one and it should render first.  I have tried to separate the js so that each has their own ready() but that didn't work.

Also:  I am more    looking for a consent on how to do this rather than the specific code.  What if I have a lot of divs with a lot of different tables.   Not every div will have a table in it.  some might have pictures or just text. There should be a way to load each div whenever it's ready to be displayed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="style/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="style/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<title>Animated jQuery Fade | Script tutorial</title>
</head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.myTable').DataTable();
});
$(document).ready(function(){$(".content").hide().fadeIn(1000);});
</script>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <h1>Welcome to test page</h1>
</div>
<div class="content" style="display: none;">
<table class="myTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php for($i =0; $i <10000; $i++){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="content" style="display: none;">
<table class="myTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php for($i =0; $i <20000; $i++){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 30,000 table rows? yeah its gonna be slow. perhaps consider using pagination

Comment: You are fading in using a class selector which is wrapping both tables, which mean that they will always fade in at the same time. This line: `$(".content").hide().fadeIn(1000);`

Comment: @andrew : This page is just an example of what I am trying.  I used 30,000 rows to show my point, that's all.

Comment: "... has their own ready()" There should only be one `$(document).ready` event on a page. Yea you can put multiples but they will all fire at the same time.

Comment: @zgood : I have tried breaking them apart and useing id's such as $("#content1".hide().fadeIn(1000); and $(#content2".... but that still rendered it at the same time.

Comment: ok, well even so, fading in the tables won't make the page load any quicker as the content still needs to be downloaded even if its hidden. I'd probably load more rows using a scroll event and ajax

Comment: The data isn't being loaded via ajax. It looks like you are writting out the data server side using php. Which means when the page loads all the data will be present for both tables.

Comment: @andrew : I don't need the page to load faster, I am working on the user experience.

Comment: @SariRahal Even with `$("#content1").hide().fadeIn(1000);` it will always fade in after 1000ms no matter what - if data is loaded or not.

Comment: @zgood : correct the data will be pulled from a database via php server side.

Comment: @SariRahal I think you need to look into loading your table data with an ajax call, then you can get the user experience you are looking for - tables fade in once their data has been loaded, you can do this with DataTables

Comment: @zgood : that is not true.  the fadIn(1000) is the duration of the fade, not when the fade will begin.  If the fadIn is set to 10, it will still take the same amount of time to render.

Comment: you need to store your data in a database, use server side to load a small set at a time, append the next set of row with ajax when user scroll down reach end.

Comment: @wlin : I am currently using jquery's datatables that paginates everything and all the data needs to be loaded before the js is ran.

Comment: @SariRahal, I think no matter what you do, even loading 30,000 table static-ly aka pure html, will be slow, especially for user running at a lesser machine.

Comment: @wlin : I understand about the amount of rows.  Currently my site does not have this many, I was just using it as an example to get my point across.

Comment: As @wlin mentioned, the way to do this with a large set of data is to store the data on the server and load it using serverside options: [serverside datatables](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)

Comment: @Aegis : What if I have a lot of divs with a lot of different tables.  I am more looking for a consent on how to do this rather than the specific code.  There should be a way to load each div whenever it's ready to be displayed.  Not every div will have a table in it.  some might have pictures or just text.

Comment: @SariRahal In that case you'll want to look into loading objects via AJAX, which will load data as and when they are ready instead of blocking the thread while everything loads. Look into the [ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) here for some more help.

Comment: @SariRahal Yes you are correct, 1000ms is the duration of the fade. I'm saying that the fadeIn will begin as soon as the page loads, as you have it written. The fadeIn will not wait until your data is loaded then fadeIn

Comment: @SariRahal I will give you an example, in a little bit, busy at work now.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need here is to provide you DataTables with an AJAX source, which will retrieve your data. Then set a callback that will fire when the data has been loaded to fadeIn your tables.

It might look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable1').dataTable( {
        "ajax"{ 
            "url": 'path/to/datasource.php',
            "success" : function(){
                 $('#myTable1').parent().fadeIn(1000);
             }
         }
    } );
} );
```

This is untested code and the syntax may be wrong, but it should give you an idea of how this is done. Also, the returned data from your php datasource must return json in the correct format DataTables is expecting (this is very important, and is often where people make mistakes).

Please see the DataTables ajax docs [here](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html).

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not about what type of data it need to display, but rather you should limit amount of data display each time, and separate the server side, from client side, so it will reduce load on browser,  the code below is untested, prob lot of syntax error @_@

PHP

```
<?php 
 // you can manual hard code the data, or use database, it really didn't matter what the data are it can be path of image, text, etc... 
 var $textData = array(); // eg ('text1','text2')
 var $imgData = array(); // eg ('path/img.jpg', 'path/img.jpg')
 var $divData = array(); // eg ('<div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>')

 // see what data set you want to get 
 if($_POST['type']==='text') {
     // now encode the data into json for ajax 
     echo json_encode($textData);
 } else if($_POST['type']==='img') {
     echo json_encode($imgData);
 } 
?>
```

JQUERY AJAX

```
<script>
if(some condition are made) {
$.ajax({
        url: "text.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            type: 'text' // it can be anything
        },
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (dataSet) {
            // jquery to append dataSet, use if() to append to different place depend on type
            // this set you can hide as default with css
            // after data loaded fade in with jquery. 
        }
    });
}   
 </script>
```